# Ошибка при создании проекта Vue-CLI 3

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Начал создавать проект Vue через UI. Под конец загрузки выкинуло ошибку:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path D:\backup\WebProjects\someProject\webapp\node_modules\.staging\aws4-94330609\aws4.js
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\backup\WebProjects\someProject\webapp\node_modules\.staging\aws4-94330609\aws4.js'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\backup\WebProjects\someProject\webapp\node_modules\.staging\aws4-94330609\aws4.js'] 
{
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\backup\WebProjects\someProject\webapp\node_modules\.staging\aws4-94330609\aws4.js'] {  
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'D:\\backup\\WebProjects\\someProject\\webapp\\node_modules\\.staging\\aws4-94330609\\aws4.js'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\backup\\WebProjects\\someProject\\webapp\\node_modules\\.staging\\aws4-94330609\\aws4.js',
npm ERR!   parent: 'webapp'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\STARK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-26T10_34_49_952Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error
Error: Command failed: vue create webapp --skipGetStarted --inlinePreset {"useConfigFiles":false,"plugins":{"@vue/cli-plugin-babel":{},"@vue/cli-plugin-router":{"historyMode":false},"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex":{},"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint":{"config":"base","lintOn":["save"]}}}
⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...


    at makeError (C:\Users\STARK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\STARK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async C:\Users\STARK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@vue\cli-ui\apollo-server\connectors\projects.js:345:5
    at async Object.wrap (C:\Users\STARK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@vue\cli-ui\apollo-server\connectors\progress.js:39:14) {   
  code: 1,
  stdout: '⚙️  Installing CLI plugins. This might take a while...\n\n',
  stderr: null,
  failed: true,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'vue create webapp --skipGetStarted --inlinePreset {"useConfigFiles":false,"plugins":{"@vue/cli-plugin-babel":{},"@vue/cli-plugin-router":{"historyMode":false},"@vue/cli-plugin-vuex":{},"@vue/cli-plugin-eslint":{"config":"base","lintOn":["save"]}}}',
  timedOut: false,
  killed: false
}
```

[image: Все что успело создастся]

Answer (score 1):

Убрал в свойствах директории "только для чтения" и все заработало.

Answer (score -1):

Запускайте terminal (или VS Code, или WebStorm) с правами админа (run as administrator).

Comment: для ms/windows это не является вредным советом?

Comment: Увы или так - или никак.

Comment: Но автор вопроса предложил [другое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131621/217579), и оно, по его словам, работает. Не поспешили ли вы с высказыванием:  _или никак_?

Comment: У меня не сработало приложенное решение. Поэтому я выложил своё (которое сработало у меня) и поэтому "или никак" - относится к тому, что иные решения мне не помогли.